# Efficient algorithm to decide if a graph is a cactus?

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

A cactus is a connected graph in which every edge belongs to at most one simple cycle.

How  should one modify the Depth First Search algorithm to obtain an efficient algorithm that determines if a given graph is a cactus?

A solution I tried exploring is to detect all the cycles in the graph and then check if there are two "nested" cycles.
However I can't determine if a cycle I found at a certain steps starts or ends inside another cycle without checking it against all the cycles I discovered before.

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected?

Comment: It is undirected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fun question!

After academic searches and Wiki came up bare, I dug through the [source code](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/b5c9cf037cbce672101725f269470135b9b2c5c4/src/sage/graphs/graph.py#L1751-L1805) of SageMath. That gets us to this:

```
#A graph is called *cactus graph* if it is connected and every pair of
simple cycles have at most one common vertex.

# Special cases
if self.order() < 4: #Number of vertices
    return True

# Every cactus graph is outerplanar
if not self.is_circular_planar():
    return False

if not self.is_connected():
    return False

# the number of faces is 1 plus the number of blocks of order > 2
B = self.blocks_and_cut_vertices()[0]
return len(self.faces()) == sum(1 for b in B if len(b) > 2) + 1
```

Determining whether the graph is connected is an *O(N)* operation. Just start a DFS at any node, keep the nodes you visit in a hashset, and then check to see that you've visited all of the nodes.

You can [check for](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.is_circular_planar) circular planarity using an *O(N)* algorithm by Boyer and Myrvold:

> John M. Boyer and Wendy J. Myrvold, On the Cutting Edge: Simplified O(n) Planarity by Edge Addition. Journal of Graph Algorithms and Applications, Vol. 8, No. 3, pp. 241-273, 2004.

And blocks and cuts [can be found](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.blocks_and_cut_vertices) using an *O(N)* algorithm by Tarjan:

> R.E. Tarjan. Depth-First Search and Linear Graph Algorithms. SIAM J. Comput. 1(2): 146-160 (1972).

You can also accelerate the SageMath implementation by [noting that](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-that-for-the-cactus-graph-number-of-edges-is-at-most-floor-1-5*-n-1-n-number-of-vertices-floor-is-rounding-down) the number of edges in a cactus graph is at most $\lfloor1.5(n-1)\rfloor$ where $n$ is the number of vertices.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an algorithm that finds all cycles, then do the following steps:

- Take cycle 1, tag all edges that are part of it.
- Take cycle 2 and go through all edges that are part of it:

  - If an edge is already tagged, then clearly that edge is part of another cycle and you don't have a cactus
  - Otherwise, tag that edge
- Repeat with cycles 3...n

Comment: Surely an algorithm that finds all cycles has exponential complexity.

Comment: Of course. I just took the OP at his word hat he can do that part of the problem.